# JQuery Calendar(http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) :Disable the passed date

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the jquery calendar to show my calendar now i am trying to disable the calendar for passed date

unfortunately i couldn't find anything to do this ?

Please help me out whether it is possible or not

Comment: Could you post the code that you are trying to use so that folks have a fighting chance to help you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery datepicker to prevent past date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786411/jquery-datepicker-to-prevent-past-date)

Comment: you have not provided any code and what about the jquery calender plugin name

Comment: Can you post the code of how you're getting the date passed in, and what you've tried, as well as your "my calendar" code?

Comment: @lc. i am using calendar not datepicker

Comment: which calender dude paste the link here

Comment: @Fluffeh  i am using http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ this link

Comment: @user1614526 i have added response

Comment: @user1614526: Your question is not very clear, In fullcalendar, We have Month view, Week View, Day View. Tell me which view, disable means you want to hide the date's

Answer (score 0):

Set minDate option as below

```
minDate: new Date()
```

in datepicker function call

That should work!!

Comment: i know Jquery Calendar is not officially release by Jquery here is the link http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ and this is not the answer of my question

Comment: Ohh, didn't notice that. Better,to use the datepicker from http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate

Answer (score 0):

search for this line in fullcalender.js

```
cell.addClass('fc-other-month');
```

change it to

```
cell.addClass('fc-other-month');
if (date < new Date())
{
    $(cell).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function then dear if not using Jquery(although i m suggesting to use jquery a better way of solution)

```
function checkdate(){
       var myDate = new Date(document.frm.date.value);
       var today = new Date();
       if (myDate<today){
         alert('You can not enter future date')
         return false;
       }
       return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({showOn: "both", minDate: 0});
});
```

Using this you will not have passed date in your datepicker....:)