# How to Datepicker picks future dates only and disable past date in JQuery and CSS?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Which class should be used for datepicker to use future dates only?

```
<form:input path="FutureDato" type="date" class="datepicker maxDateToday hasDatepicker" />
```

**Note**: The code is written by someone else. The above code does not allow to enter future date or you can say disable future dates on calendar click. I want code to disable past dates and show future date years only. I am unable to get how these classes (datepicker, maxDateToday) worked here; unable to find it in CSS. I do not know whether above execute by JQuery; if yes then i am unable to search the same. If such classes are predefined then could you please help me finding the class?

Comment: There is no special class for that, you specifiy that in the settings when you instantiate a datepicker.

Comment: So this code must be there in some jquery?

Comment: Somewhere you have javascript that creates the datepicker, and there are settings where you can set the max and min dates.

Comment: The developer of code is someone else and is not in contact. I need to find it and there are many js files. Opened code in Netbeans. Any famous keywords other then datepicker you can suggest?

Comment: Nope, it's generally `$(element).datepicker({settings})`

Comment: It Says maxDate: 0 i think we will use minDate=0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786411/jquery-datepicker-to-prevent-past-date

Comment: could you please put it to answer "minDate: 0"? i will accept that as answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To make any past dates unselectable, you first have to find the instantiation of the datepicker, and set the `minDate` setting to zero.

```
$('element').datepicker({
    minDate : 0
});
```

Comment: In case someone wants to limit date selection to future dates but after today, you can do `minDate: '+1D'` (or +1w, etc).

Answer (score 10):

Best solution for disable past dates and picks only future dates is:

Try this, it is working in my case:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ 
    startDate: new Date()   
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Use datepicker's minDate() method you can find api details http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
     minDate: new Date()
});
```

for this first you have to import jQuery-UI script https://code.jquery.com/ui/

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 2):

To make any past dates disable or for only future dates, you first have to find the instantiation of the datepicker, and set the startDate setting to '+0d'.

```
$('element').datepicker({
    startDate: '+0d'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found, in my particular case, that it only worked if using `setDefaults`. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready( function ( e ) {
        if ( jQuery( '.your-date-picker-selector' ).length ) {
            jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({
                minDate: 0,
                maxDate: "+12m"
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```