# jQuery Datepicker Overlaps With Previously Submitted Input Field

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

[image: Datepicker overlapping with previous input]

I am using jQuery Datepicker on a form that is being submitted and it is implemented on an input field.
When I click on the input field to choose another date, previously submitted dates appear on the field and it partially blocks the UI of the date picker.
Is there any clean solution for this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I think this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786411/jquery-datepicker-to-prevent-past-date

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the link. I don't need to disable past (or future) dates in my datepicker. I just needed to eliminate the display of history of previous date submissions.

Comment: $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0}); not working for you?

Comment: No, it does not work in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your input filed's autocomplete property is set to on. set autocomplete to off.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: This solved my issue! I totally forgot this property. Thank you very much.