# want to disable all the previous dates jquery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to disable all the previous dates using `jquery datetimepicker`.

It will show just datetimes from today onward:

```
<script>/*
window.onerror = function(errorMsg) {
  $('#console').html($('#console').html()+'<br>'+errorMsg)
}*/

$.datetimepicker.setLocale('en');

$('#datetimepicker_format').datetimepicker({value:'2015/04/15 05:03', format: $("#datetimepicker_format_value").val()});
console.log($('#datetimepicker_format').datetimepicker('getValue'));

$("#datetimepicker_format_change").on("click", function(e){
  $("#datetimepicker_format").data('xdsoft_datetimepicker').setOptions({format: $("#datetimepicker_format_value").val()});
});
$("#datetimepicker_format_locale").on("change", function(e){
  $.datetimepicker.setLocale($(e.currentTarget).val());
});

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
dayOfWeekStart : 1,
lang:'en',
disabledDates:['1986/01/08','1986/01/09','1986/01/10'],
startDate:  '1986/01/05'
});
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({value:'2015/04/15 05:03',step:10});

$('.some_class').datetimepicker();
$('#datetimepicker_mask').datetimepicker({
  mask:'9999/19/39 29:59'
});

$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  datepicker:false,
  format:'H:i',
  step:5
});
$('#datetimepicker_dark').datetimepicker({theme:'dark'})


</script>
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: i think question is very clear

Comment: include `minDate: 0` in your options, as described [here](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#minDate)

Comment: @PaulRoub do not know where to edit, can u help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery datepicker to prevent past date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786411/jquery-datepicker-to-prevent-past-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `mindate` value to `today`

e.g

```
var today = new Date();
```

Then insert it to your `datetimepicker()`

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
dayOfWeekStart : 1,
lang:'en',
disabledDates:['1986/01/08','1986/01/09','1986/01/10'],
startDate:  '1986/01/05',
minDate:today //added parameter to disable past dates
})
```